# Button alignment is not proper in FF?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have a html button with below CSS.

```
.myButton{
    background: url("../images/button.png") no-repeat top left;
    height: 21px;
    width: 78px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #696969;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: medium none white;
}
```

It renders nicely in IE. But in Fire Fox it does not render the text in center. It renders as below:

[image]

How can I align the text to center in FF. In IE it is proper?

Comment: Maybe button width more that background image, try background: url("../images/button.png") no-repeat 50% 0;

Comment: This CSS will render the text centered as intended. If it's not rendering correctly that means you have other CSS affecting the result.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `background: url("../images/button.png") no-repeat top left` to background: `url("../images/button.png") no-repeat top center` and is working fine....

Answer (score 0):

There must be additional CSS code that applies to your button. With only the given CSS the button looks different: http://jsfiddle.net/xQmHA/

```
<button class="myButton">TEST</button>
```

You can check which style rules apply to your button from within Firefox (F12 --> CSS --> Select your button)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
      .myButton{
            padding:0;
            background: url("../images/button.png") no-repeat top left;
            height: 21px;
            line-height: 21px;
            width: 78px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #696969;
            font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            border: medium none white;
            outline:0 none;
    }
```

You need to reset default style sheet of any browser before adding your styles. In this case I suspect it is the padding that is by default added by FF/IE that makes it not work for you.

Please find an Appropriate reset style for the Element before you add your own.